# Google BigQuery: Move Data from one Location to Another

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 BigQuery Datasets - one based in the US and the other in London.

I want to move the data from the US location table to London location table using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `London_Dataset.TARGET_TABLE`
SELECT * FROM `US_Dataset.SOURCE_TABLE`
```

However, the SQL fails as if I process the query in US location then it cannot find the London dataset and vice-versa.

Can anyone please give me ideas to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot,
Sri.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [copy dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) or [move it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#moving_datasets).
[image]